# How to draw a line graph with a given slope?

Tags: linegraph

The abline can be used to draw a regression line after plotted the data. Let say only the slope is given, how can i draw a line graph using the slope? The slope is -4/3. Is there any function generate a line graph using slope only?

Thank you.

Comment: What language or software tool are you using?  Or is this simply a math question?

Comment: Mathematically, a line is _y = a + bx_ where _a_ is the _y_-intercept and _b_ is the slope.  If you know _b_ and assume _a_ is zero (i.e. the line passes through the origin) then it's simply _y = bx_.  So plotting _bx_ gives you a line with slope _b_.

Comment: A slope is insufficient to identify a unique line. You need a slope and a point. (Perhaps the point is the origin?) I'm guessing you're using R since it has a function called `abline()`.

Comment: Yes. I using abline(). Any function in R generate the data points based on a given slope?